# How do you prove $f(x)=\begin{cases}11&0\leq x \leq 1 \\ x& 1 <x \leq 2\end{cases}$ is continuous on [0,1)?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}11&0\leq x \leq 1 \\ x& 1 <x \leq 2\end{cases}$$

How do you prove it is continuous on the interval [0,1) ?

The definition of continuity I am using is as follows: Take a sequence $x_n \to x_0$ such that $x_n \in [0,1)$, then f is continuous if the sequence $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$.

Here is my thought process: 
Let $x_n \to x_0$ be a sequence in [0,1).  I need to somehow show $f(x_n) \to f(x_o)$.  This amounts to showing for any given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that if $n \geq N $ then $| f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

So let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $x_n \to x_0$, we know ($\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$)($ n \geq N \implies |x_n -x_0| < \epsilon$)

This means $-\epsilon < x_n - x_0 < \epsilon $ if $n \geq N$

But I am lost at this point, how do I show $| f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Why not just keep doing what you're doing and plug in the values of $f(x_n)$ and $f(x_0)$? Should be pretty simple to show that $|f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for $x_n$, and $x_0$ in $[0, 1)$! Also be careful using the same epsilon for the distance in the image and the distance in the domain.

Comment: @Nadiels - yes, but what exactly am I plugging in ? $x_n$ supposed to be any sequence in [0,1) interval. Since it can be any sequence, there aren't any values that I can plugin to f(x).

Comment: I am sure someone will give a fully fleshed answer momentarily, but lets say you have $N$ such that $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$, well we want to check that we have made our $N$ large enough so that the value of $f(x_n)$ gets arbitrarily close to the value of $f(x_0)$, i.e. $|f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$, but what *is* $f(x_n) - f(x_0)$?